# Why can't onDraw() access myPaint?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, canvas, scope

I am creating a simple drawing of a circle using `Canvas` and `Paint`.

I noticed that when I create the variable `myPaint` outside of `init()`, everything works perfectly fine; illustrated by the following code:

```
public class Drawing extends View {

    Paint myPaint;
    public Drawing(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public void init(){
        myPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        myPaint.setColor(Color.parseColor("yellow"));
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        canvas.drawCircle(getMeasuredWidth() /2, getMeasuredHeight() /2 , 100f, myPaint);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```

However, when I do the exact same thing, but instead create `myPaint` inside of `init()`, I get an error for `myPaint` in `onDraw()`; illustrated by the following code:

```
public class Drawing extends View {


public Drawing(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public void init(){
    Paint myPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    myPaint.setColor(Color.parseColor("yellow"));
}


@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    canvas.drawCircle(getMeasuredWidth() /2, getMeasuredHeight() /2 , 100f, myPaint);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
}
```

Why is this so? Thanks!

Comment: See: [What is 'scope' in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38177140/295004)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In code B you're defining a local variable which is only accessible inside the code block it has been defined in (which is `init` method in this case). In contrast, code A defines a property which is accessible inside your object and leaves side by side of it.

You can also take a look at [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/What-are-class-variables-instance-variables-and-local-variables-in-Java#:%7E:text=Instance%20variables%20%E2%88%92%20Instance%20variables%20are,class%2C%20but%20outside%20a%20method.&text=Local%20variables%20are%20created%20when,method%2C%20constructor%2C%20or%20block.).

> **Instance variables** are declared in a class, but outside a method. When
> space is allocated for an object in the heap, a slot for each instance
> variable value is created. Instance variables hold values that must be
> referenced by more than one method, constructor or block, or essential
> parts of an object's state that must be present throughout the class.
>
> **Local variables** are declared in methods, constructors, or blocks.
> Local variables are created when the method, constructor or block is
> entered and the variable will be destroyed once it exits the method,
> constructor, or block.