# Storing each digit of an integer into an ArrayList java

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying make a Digits method that stores digit of the num that is passed in in an ArrayList digitList. Instead of dividing by 10 and getting the modulus, I am converting the integer num to a string and trying to store each digit using charAt. But I must convert it back to integer to store it in the ArrayList and struggling on how to do it.

Thank you very much!

```
 class Digits{
 
 ArrayList<Integer>digitList;

Digits(int num) {
    String StringN = Integer.toString(num);
    int index = 0;
    new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
    for(int i=0;i<StringN.length();i++) {

        // convert the charAt(i) to integer here?

        digitList.add(index, StringN.charAt(i)); 
  
        index++;
    }
    


      }
 }

 public class digitListclass {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    
    

}

 }
```

Comment: what is "digitList cannot be resolved" trying to tell you?

Comment: I have no idea, did I declare the ArrayList incorrectly?

Comment: This might help you: [What is 'scope' in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38177140/what-is-scope-in-java). You created a local variable in your main method. The scope of that variable is only that method.

Comment: @Selina you did not declare `digitList` anywhere.

Comment: I edited my code!  how could I store charAt(i) as an integer in the digitList

Comment: I think the simplest way is `charAt(i) - '0'`.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

Use Unicode code points rather than `char`, as a best practice.

```java
"1234567890"
        .codePoints()
        .map( 
            ( int codePoint ) -> Integer.parseInt( Character.toString( codePoint ) ) 
        )
        .boxed()
        .toList()
```

> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]

## `char` obsolete

The `char` type is obsolete, unable to represent even half of the characters defined in Unicode. While this type would work for strictly [Arabic numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_numerals), we should make a habit of using [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) integer numbers rather than `char` type values.

### `IntStream` of code points

The easiest way to work with text as code point numbers is to call [`String#codePoints`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#codePoints()) to get an [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html), a stream of `int` primitive values. For digit `1`, we get code point 49, for digit `2` code point 50, and so on, with `0` being assigned to code point 48.

For each `int` representing a code point number, convert to the character assigned to that number as a `String` object. So 49 becomes "1", 50 becomes "2", and so on.

Then parse each digit-as-string into an `int` value for the digit value. Throws a [`NumberFormatException`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html) if the string is not a parsable integer.

By calling `.boxed`, we convert each `int` primitive for the digit to an `Integer` object.

Lastly, we collect the `Integer` objects representing each digit into an unmodifiable `List`. The [`Stream#toList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toList()) method is new in Java 16. For earlier Java, use `.collect( Collectors.toList() )`.

```java
List < Integer > digits =
        "1234567890"
                .codePoints()
                .map( codePoint -> Integer.parseInt( Character.toString( codePoint ) ) )
                .boxed()
                .toList();
```

Here is a full working example class with `main` method.

```java
package work.basil.demo.text;

import java.util.List;

public class App2
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        List < Integer > digits =
                "1234567890"
                        .codePoints()
                        .map( codePoint -> Integer.parseInt( Character.toString( codePoint ) ) )
                        .boxed()
                        .toList();

        System.out.println( "digits = " + digits );
    }
}
```

When run.

> digits = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]

Answer (score 0):

This might help you -

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {
  List<Integer> toList(int num) {
    String stringNumber = Integer.toString(num);
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>(stringNumber.length());
    for(int i = 0; i < stringNumber.length(); i ++) {
      result.add(Integer.valueOf(stringNumber.substring(i, i + 1)));
    }
    return result;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(new Test().toList(1234567890));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there are some problems in your code:

1. Your way of initializing `digitList` is not correct since it's not being assigned to any variable. You should rather do:

```
this.digitList = new ArrayList<>();
```

2. I think you have a redundant `index` variable for your loop as it doesn't seem to be getting used anywhere. You should remove it and just use `i`.
3. You should keep your class variables `private` by default and `final` if they are not supposed to be changed. Use getters and setters for accessing variable.

I modified your code like this:

```java
class Digits {
    private final ArrayList<Integer> digitList;

    public Digits(int num) {
        this.digitList = new ArrayList<>();
        initDigitList(num);
    }

    private void initDigitList(int num) {
        String stringN = Integer.toString(num);
        for (int i = 0; i < stringN.length(); i++) {
            // convert the charAt(i) to integer here?
            digitList.add(i, stringN.charAt(i) - '0');
        }
    }

    public List<Integer> getDigitList() {
        return this.digitList;
    }
}
```

I tested it with this code and it seems to work:

```
Digits first = new Digits(512);
Digits second = new Digits(1024);

// Prints First Digit: [5, 1, 2]
System.out.println("First Digit: " + first.getDigitList().toString());
// Prints Second Digit: [1, 0, 2, 4]
System.out.println("Second Digit: " + second.getDigitList().toString());
```