# How do I avoid multiple print statements in 'if' block Java

Tags: java, if-statement

[Can't access that nett at the end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btUpR.png)

I have the code in the picture and I cannot access the nett variable for my print statement at the end.

I can access this in a python copy of the same script

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: [What is 'scope' in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38177140/what-is-scope-in-java)