# Filename cannot be resolved to a variable in a Java method when referencing to an argument in a command line

Tags: java, eclipse, class, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to avoid hard-coding file names in my Java class and want to pass them as the command line arguments in Eclipse, e.g. "JSONDataStore_complex.json topicdatanew.txt".

my code is as follows:

```
public class B4TopicModelling {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        
        if (args.length == 2) {
            B4TopicModelling loader = new B4TopicModelling();

            String filePath = args[0];    // e.g. "JSONDataStore_complex.json"
            String TMFlatFile = args[1]; // e.g. "topicdatanew.txt"

            System.out.println("Start Topic Modelling :" + filePath);
            loader.StartTopicModellingProcess(filePath);
            
            int numTopics = 10; // the number of topics (or groups we'll cluster the documents into)
            int numThreads = 2; // how many threads it will use (helping speed up the process on machines with multiple cores)
            int numIterations = 500; // how many times the process is run
            int numTopWords = 10; // the top ten words per topic
            
            loader.RunTopicModelling(TMFlatFile, numTopics, numThreads, numIterations, numTopWords);

        } else {
            System.err.println("Error: No valid arguments have been entered.");
        }
    }     

    private void StartTopicModellingProcess(String filePath) {
        JSONIOHelper jsonIO = new JSONIOHelper(); // create an object of the JSONIOHelper class
        jsonIO.LoadJSON(filePath); // call the LoadJSON method
        ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> lemmas = jsonIO.GetDocumentsFromJSONStructure();

//      String TMFlatFile = "topicdata_new.txt";
        SaveLemmaDataToFile(TMFlatFile, lemmas);

    }

    private void SaveLemmaDataToFile(String TMFlatFile, ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> lemmas) {

        // create a for loop which saves each entry in the ConcurrentHashMap called
        // lemmas into the file with the name TMFlatFile.
        try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(TMFlatFile)) {

            // Write our string to our file

            for (Entry<String, String> entry : lemmas.entrySet()) {
                // Saves the keys then tab then 'en' and tab and the lemmas entries
                writer.write(entry.getKey() + "\ten\t" + entry.getValue() + "\r\n");
            }

            System.out.println("TMFlatFile File saved successfully...");

        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Saving TMFlatFile to text file failed...");
        }

    }

    private void RunTopicModelling(String TMFlatFile, int numTopics, int numThreads, int numIterations, int numTopWords) {
        ArrayList<Pipe> pipeList = new ArrayList<Pipe>();

        // Pipes: tokenise, map to features
        pipeList.add(new CharSequence2TokenSequence(Pattern.compile("\\p{L}[\\p{L}\\p{P}]+\\p{L}")));
//      pipeList.add(new TokenSequenceRemoveStopwords(new File("stoplist_en.txt"), "UTF-8", false, false, false));
        pipeList.add(new TokenSequence2FeatureSequence());

        InstanceList instances = new InstanceList(new SerialPipes(pipeList));

        InputStreamReader fileReader = null;
        // loads the file passed in via the TMFlatFile variable into the fileReader
        // variable

        try {

            File inFile = new File(TMFlatFile);

            fileReader = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(inFile));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("File Load failed");
            System.exit(1);

        }
        // linking data to the pipeline
        instances
                .addThruPipe(new CsvIterator(fileReader, Pattern.compile("^(\\S*)[\\s,]*(\\S*)[\\s,]*(.*)$"), 3, 2, 1));

        // Setting up the Parallel Topic Model

        ParallelTopicModel model = new ParallelTopicModel(numTopics, 1.0, 0.01);

        model.addInstances(instances);
        model.setNumThreads(numThreads);
        model.setNumIterations(numIterations);

        try {
            model.estimate();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Model estimation failed...");
        }

    }

}
```

The line with "SaveLemmaDataToFile(TMFlatFile, lemmas)" gives me an error,

```
 TMFlatFile cannot be resolved to a variable.
```

If I uncomment "String TMFlatFile = "topicdata_new.txt";" this will work.
however, I do not understand how to supply this filename as a command line argument in Eclipse instead? Is it possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is 'scope' in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38177140/what-is-scope-in-java)

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with that you pass the filename as an argument into the main method. You simply try to access a variable in another method where it isn't in scope. Either pass the variable into that method or change the scope of the variable. eG you already pass `String filePath` from your main method ti your other method as an argument. simply do the same for the `TMFlatFile` variable.

Comment: you mean I should do StartTopicModellingProcess(String filePath, String TMFlatFile) ?   sorry if thats a beginner question.

Comment: Yes, that would be the easiest way to do it.