# ArrayList size as a variable

Tags: java, arraylist

Why can't I save ArrayList size as a variable?

```
public static ArrayList <Integer > merge(ArrayList <Integer > list1,
                                          ArrayList <Integer > list2 ) {

    if (list1.size() >= list2.size()) {
        int maxSize = list1.size(); 
    } else {
        int maxSize = list2.size();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < maxSize; i++) {

        if (i <= list2.size()) {
            int nextInList2 = list2.get(i);
            list1.add(i, nextInList2);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(list1);
    return (list1);
```

in:
int maxSize = list1.size();
I assume that it's not saving the variable as I want to.

I assume that

```
list1.size()
```

is an integer

Comment: of course you can save them, and you are doing so, but you declare those ints in those if-else blocks, meaning they don't exist outside of the scope of them. declare the variable before the if, and just assign the value in the if-else blocks to solve your issues

Comment: You define the variable inside curly braces. It does not exist outside of those braces. That is called the scope of the variable.

Comment: You need to understand a lot more about scopes. Currently your variable maxSize is only working in the scope of if.

Comment: You are misinterpreting the error you get. Of course you can save the size in an in t variable and you do that at 2 places in your code. Your error is however that you try to use those maxSize variables outside their scope. See [What is 'scope' in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38177140/what-is-scope-in-java)

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/TOC.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### TLDR;

Just declare maxSize above the if and else statements. And Bob's your uncle. Then you can use maxSize everywhere in your method/function.

### Solution

This is a scope problem. To solve your issue, declare the variable (maxSize) outside the brackets of the if-else statement.
When you declare them in the brackets, you will only be able to use them within them (Scope).

```
int maxSize = 0;
if (list1.size() >= list2.size()) {
    maxSize = list1.size(); 
} else {
    maxSize = list2.size();
}

// Now maxSize can be used as you wish :)
for (int i = 0; i < maxSize; i++) { ...
```

**Notes:**

- As @berse2212 pointed out if you add or remove items to your array, you need to update your maxSize again.
- Also, like with @so-random-dude showed, you can replace the if else statement with this gem :

> int maxSize = Math.max(list1.size(), list2.size());

### What on earth is Scope about?

Scope defines the lifetime of a variable. Let's take a deeper look at your example. For simplicity, let us ignore the else.

```
...
    if (list1.size() >= list2.size()) {
        // Start If statement's Scope. 
        int maxSize = list1.size(); // Add maxSize to scope
        // Max Size is in scope and can be used as you wish
        // End the scope, in other words, maxSize does not exist anymore.
    }

// maxSize has left the building, and the compiler does not know about it.
...
```

This is just a small example. But you can find more (and better) information [here](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_scope.asp) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38177140/what-is-scope-in-java)

Hope this helps

Comment: Just a small addition - be careful if you store the size in a Variable because it does not get updated when the size of the ArrayList increases or decreases.

Comment: @berse2212 Good point, I added to the answer for completeness :)

Comment: Is there any benefit to initializing maxSize to 0? Yes, I know, "All variables must be initialized!!!!!" But you *are* initializing maxSize, in row 3 or 5. AFAICT the only effect this dummy-initialization has is suppressing the compiler warning if you forget the real initialization in one of the branches.

Comment: Hi @Sören! Maybe consider asking a question or searching SO on this one. There is a lot to unpack in your simple question, but let me try. First, Not *All* variables should be initialized; only local ones (Fields or instance-level variables will be set to a default value).  Secondly, it is not a compiler warning, it is a compiler error when a local variable is not initiated(code will not compile). Finally, in the example above, there will be no error if not initiated, as the compiler is smart enough to evaluate if-else statements. Change it to an if-else-if then there will be a compiler error.

Comment: Finally - I assigned it to 0, as the main focus of the question is regarding "the scope" and not initialising variables.  It is a matter of preference, not a matter of any advantages.

Answer (score 2):

As others have already pointed out, it's indeed a scope problem. The variable `maxSize` is born and died with in the `if` block (and another one with the same name again in the `else` block - See, compiler didn't complain even when you had 2 reference variables with the same name, one in the if block and another one in the else block - Because compiler knows that the `maxSize` that you created in the `if` is out-of-scope for `else` ).

What Reg given is the correct solution

The following is just a different, concise way to solve the problem

You can use **ternary operator** like this

```
int maxSize = (list1.size() >= list2.size()) ? list1.size() : list2.size();
```

Or even better

```
int maxSize = Math.max(list1.size(), list2.size());
```

Also, next time, when you ask the question, try to isolate the problem and eliminate all the unnecessary details. For example, in this case, if you have tried

```
if (true) {
        int maxSize = 1; 
    } else {
        int maxSize = 2;
    }

System.out.println(maxSize); // Compiler will scream at you.
```

you could have avoided talking about arrayList and come to the crux of the problem. See, arrayList was just a red herring, Probably you could have figured it all by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The variable is scoped to the `if`, declare it outside to bring it to scope:

```java
int maxSize;
if (condition) {
   maxSize = ... 
} else {
   maxSize = ... 
}
// now can be used in the for
for (int i = 0; i < maxSize; i++ ) {
}
```

As pointed in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74462094/20654), you can also use the ternary operator

```java
int maxSize = list1.size() >= list2.size() ? list1.size() : list2.size(); 
for (int i = 0; i < maxSize; i++ ) {
}
```

Just be aware to balance readability.